# Core Data and Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have an iOS app I'm building that I am preloading csv values into a table view and using core data, which is working great. My issue is, when I press a row I need to grab data from that specific row and pass it to my next view. I am able to do this using an array listed in a table view but can't figure out how to do this with core data. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you do it with Core Data? You have logic in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the right data for the row, correct? Use the same logic to get the data in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @rmaddy has it exactly right.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. Do I use didSelectRowAtIndexPath in my table view controller or my other view controller?

Comment: It needs to be in the view controller with the table view since that is where a row is selected.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again!